# What HTTP status code is most search-engine-friendly during a planned outage?

Tags: seo, http-status-codes

If you have to take a site down for some type of unavoidable maintenance task (and it's not a big enough site that you have a backup server), what HTTP status code should you have your server return to minimize the possibility that search engines will think the site is gone?

I found [this list of status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) from W3C, of which the following seem applicable:

- 503 Service Unavailable
- 500 Internal Server Error
- 408 Timeout
- 404 Not Found

I think 503 is the most appropriate, but I don't know what search engines might prefer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[From the horse's mouth](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-about-googlebot.html):

> **If my site is down for maintenance, how can I tell Googlebot to come back later rather than to index the "down for maintenance" page?**
>
> You should configure your server to return a status of 503 (network unavailable) rather than 200 (successful). That lets Googlebot know to try the pages again later.

Answer (score 3):

Don't send a 404 -- they may remove you from their index.

I'd probably send a 503 and an appropriate Retry-After, although I don't know if anything actually uses the header.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40132) the 503 code would be the way to go, since it means "the server is temporarily unavailable."
Also check out [the W3C page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) on the same.